Set tick labels format automatically
There are new requirements at my work regarding the format of tick labels on the graph. Formerly they used to be indifferent to a format, so it could be like "1,5e-7", but now they demand to use, for example, "1; 1,5; 2..." if possible and "1·10-7; 1,5·10-7; 2·10-7" otherwise. But in a gnuplot script I can use only one kind of formatting for the axis at the same time, like %g or %t^{%T}. Is there a way to set the format like %g but to change "eX" to "·10X"?

Do I understand correctly, you want to avoid labels like 1*10^0, 1.5*10^0, ...? Or also labels like 1.0*10^7, but instead 1*10^7. What about 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500?  And then change to 1*10^3 ? Maybe you could list a few more formatted labels which you don't want to see and a few more which you want to see instead. I assume you want autoscale and you don't know the data range in advance, correct?

@theozh I want a format like "%g" where it's decided automatically whether to use "eX" or not, but the only difference is to change "eX" to "*10^X".

@theozh yes, I want autoscale. I'm creating gnuplot scripts for 100s of graphs using a python script and it would be difficult for me to work with every graph individually.

Not sure if set format "%h" is the solution you are looking for. Check the different formats for x- and y-axes.
From help format_specifiers:
%h or %H %g with "x10^{%S}" or "*10^{%S}" instead of "e%S" 

Script:
### different tic formats
reset session

set xrange[1e-9:1e9]

set logscale x
set logscale y

set format x "%g"
set format y "%h"

plot x
### end of script

Result:


Thanks, it works but produces the 'x' sign with both '%h' and '%H' specifiers and not the dot sign.

@Michael well, I'm not sure, but if you want to exchange x by the dot sign, you probably have to do it "manually", i.e. a large extra script probably with some limitations in order to do it "fully automatic".

Found a line in src/util.c, replaced \xc3\x97 with \xc2\xb7, now I have a dot :)

@Michael ah, good point, if you are compiling from the source.

@Michael, by the way... I was checking the documentation again. %h apparently gives a cross, but if I am using %H, I get a dot instead of a star (unlike documentation says). So, no need to change the source code. But this might also depend on the operating system.
